# How to merge Access DB table into a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server table that has a unique field which matches a unique field in an Access DB table.

I need to get the Access DB table into the SQL Server table based on that field.

How do I go about doing this?

I want to say a JOIN, but a JOIN is just a temporary query, isn't it? I want this to be permanent. I want the Access DB table data merged into SQL Server table based on this unique field.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

---

The reason I need this separate is that a software is reading this SQL Server data, so I need it all in the same table.

Comment: Try the import wizard of SQL Server for this task.
Have a look at this link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Answer (score 0):

B,

I believe what you would be looking for is Union

With the two tables being

HumanResources.Employees and HumanResources.Employees2

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM HumanResources.Employees
UNION
SELECT ID, Name FROM HumanResources.Employees2
```

Comment: That is wrong. He is looking for a way to merge Access DB and SQL Server.